# Search box form not taking on CSS styling from external style sheet

Tags: html, css

I have an external style sheet for and html page I am working on. The CSS file in linked properly and the page is taking on the styling except for the form I added for a search box. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>ASA Databse</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Autism Resources</h1>
    <form align="center">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Query..." required>
        <input type="button" value="Search Database">
    </form>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Item Number</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>Charles d'Orleans</td>
            <td>Poemes</td>
            <td class="money"></td>
            <td class="money">$5,866.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>T.S. Eliot</td>
            <td>Poems 1909 - 1925</td>
            <td class="money">$1,250.00</td>
            <td class="money">$8,499.35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>Sylvia Plath</td>
            <td>The Colossus</td>
            <td class="money"></td>
            <td class="money">$1031.72</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
 body {
            font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
            color: #111111;}
        table {
            width: 1000px;}
        th, td {
            padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;}
        th {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
            font-size: 90%;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #111111;
            border-top: 1px solid #999;
            text-align: left;}
        tr.even {
            background-color: #efefef;}
        tr:hover {
            background-color: #207cca;}
        .money {
            text-align: right;}
        form {
            width: 500px;
            margin: 50px auto;}
        .search {
            padding: 8px 15px;
            background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
            border: 0px solid #dbdbdb;}
        .button {
            position: relative;
            padding: 6px, 15px;
            left:-8px;
            border: 2px solid #207cca;
            background-color: #207cca;
            color: #fafafa;}
        .button:hover {
            background-color:#fafafa;
            color:#207cca;}
```

After the form's width and margin none of the styling is being implemented into the search bar... Thank you ahead of time for your help!

Comment: Did you use the Chrome Inspector (or any debugger) to view exactly which stylesheets are being applied to the form object?

Comment: No I'm not.  I'm guessing thats a chrome extension? I'll get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `.search` in your stylesheet, but no element with `class="search"`.

Try:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Query..." id="search" class="search" name="search" required>
```

Comment: Just thought i'd mention that I believe you just need the 'class="search"' portion. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, you're right @Edge, but... `name="search"` will be needed if a `<label>` is added at any point in the future and while `class="search"` is handy for css, `id="search"` makes it straightforward to `getElementById` in javascript at any point in the future. (That's why I added all three!) Please accept the answer above if it works for you - many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Dot means class in CSS and your elements do not have classes.